# If $(a_n)$ is bounded, show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{n+1}-a_n \over \sqrt{n}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to show that if a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ is bounded, then the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{n+1}-a_n \over \sqrt{n}}$$
converges. I would appreciate any clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This directly follows from the [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)

Comment: How do I show that the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)$ is in fact bounded? From $\lvert a_n \rvert \leq m$ I get $$\lvert a_{n+1}-a_n \rvert \leq \lvert a_{n+1} \rvert + \lvert a_{n} \rvert \leq 2m$$ This is not quite enough to show that the sequence of partial sums is bounded, though.

Comment: Do it like this: $|(a_{n+1}-a_n)+(a_n-a_{n-1})+...+(a_2-a_1)| = |a_{n+1} - a_1|\leq 2\sup_k|a_k|<\infty$, for every integer $n$.